# JavaScript eslint error - Don't make functions under loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I am writing an automated test script in JavaScript (NodeJS) with `cucumber framework`. One of my step definition needs to call API and reads the `JSON` data.

In the below code ptRecords is block of JSON response in which I am reading a element called `jsonElement1` and `jsonElement2`, these two elements repeats several times , hence I am reading all the occurrences..

My below code works fine but when I run lint, it throws lint error saying don't make functions under loop statement.

Could you please advise how to call these outside loop and get the response back..

I need to do this until **K loop ends**

```
for (let k = 0; k < 5; k += 1) {
  ptRecords.forEach((jsonArrObj1) => {
    const jsonArrObjTagValue = objectHelpers.walk(jsonArrObj1.jsonElement1);
    acc.push(jsonArrObjTagValue1);
  });

  ptRecords.forEach((jsonArrObj2) => {
    const jsonArrObjTagValue = objectHelpers.walk(jsonArrObj2.jsonElement2);
    acc.push(jsonArrObjTagValue2);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to change this:

```
for (let k = 0; k < 5; k += 1) {
  // ...
}
```

into:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(k => {
  // ...
});
```

or you can use some shortcut to auto-generate the array:

```
[...Array(5).keys()].forEach(k => {
  // ...
});
```

or:

```
[...Array(5)].forEach((v, k) => {
  // ...
});
```

Or sometimes your best bet can be to disable a certain rule if you know what you're doing:

```
// eslint-disable-line no-loop-func
```

Comment: thanks for varies possible ways . It was helpful for me :)